# How to migrate from Svelte rollup.js to SvelteKit?

Tags: javascript, migration, rollupjs, svelte-3, sveltekit

I've got a working svelte webapp running with rollup.js. On extending it, I learnt of SvelteKit and realise that it's a better match for my project. How can I migrate from rollup.js to SvelteKit?

Comment: Are you using Sapper? or just straight Rollup? There's decent migration documentation here: [Migration](https://kit.svelte.dev/migrating) which is sapper specific, but will also point to all the areas you'll need to address coming from Rollup.

Comment: @pilchard I've never used Sapper, just the rollup template

Comment: Aha, I found that documentation googling but figured it wouldn't help me as I was using rollup, not sapper.

Comment: You won't be able to follow it step for step, but it should give a decent outline of areas that need attention. It's going to be some large refactoring to take advantage of the built in patterns of SvelteKit

Comment: Any luck with that?

Comment: @NickAlves I basically started over and copied what code I could.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the updated URL for migrating to sveltekit from sapper:

https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/migrating

The key point you're probably looking for is to move configuration from your rollup.config.js to svelte.config.js

Preprocessor options are there under config.preprocess

So your svelte.config.js might end up looking like this:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
import image from "svelte-image";

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: [
        preprocess(),
        image(),
    ],
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter(),

        // Override http methods in the Todo forms
        methodOverride: {
            allowed: ['PATCH', 'DELETE']
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```